# HTML Language question

Tags: html, xhtml, internationalization

Note my code below.  I am trying to figure out why my data is not changing to Spanish.  I understand it to be one line of code and that is all within the HTML attribute  `lang=”es”`.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xlmns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang=”es” xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>


<link href="javajam.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="brown">
 <h1>JavaJam Coffee House</h1>



  <ul>
    <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
    <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
    <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>   
    <li>Usability Studies</li>
    <li>Open Mic Night</li>
  </ul>
<br></br>
  <p>12312 Main Street<br> 
 Mountain Home, CA 93923<br>
 1-888-555-5555</br>

</p>
<p> <em> <small>Copyright &copy; 2008 JavaJam Coffee House</em></p>
E-Mail <a href="mailto;mlj0102@embarqmail.com"> Michael J. Crawley</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using the code button when entering your html
And update your copyright notice :)

Comment: Thanks..  I was not sure how add the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Automatic translation is not a feature for all browsers. You need to make a seperate Spanish page yourself.

---

Also,

```
lang=”es”
```

you're using the wrong quotation mark

```
lang="es"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `lang="es"` attribute doesn't translate your page into Spanish. It's meant to be a simple declaration that the page is in Spanish.  But your page is in English.

Comment: Well that makes sense! Is there to convert this page to Spanish w/o the manual process of typing it?